# What does the ^= operator do to a boolean in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I've never seen this one before, and I want to know how it affects booleans in case I ever need it. Does it just make a false boolean true and vice versa, or is it not even a real operator? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It's real. Try it and see. The English is *exclusive or*.

Comment: `a ^= b` is the same as `a = a ^ b`, where `^` is "xor".  `a ^= true` is equivalent to `a = !a`.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a name, @ElliottFrisch, now everyone can use their search engine and find more (it’s hard with just `^=`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^ is XOR, means result can only be true if the arguments are true and false but not both true or both false.

Example:

**T xor F is True**

**F xor T is True**

**T xor T is False**

**F xor F is False**

So if a = T and b = F,

a^=b is a = a^b implies a = T xor F